# How to initialize the bean when the custom scope is created

Tags: java, spring

I have a custom scope defined for my Spring configuration, I want to initialize some of my beans "right after" my custom scope is created. At the moment my bean is not initialized because probably it is not called on right time when the scope is ready yet.

"myScope" is created through Java code.

```
<bean id="myAdvice" class="com.myclass" scope="myScope">
 <property name="name1" ref="ref1" />     
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "myScope" is created through Java code.

Well then either switch to XML or to [Java-based configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). If you do, your scope can have [lifecycle callback methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lifecycle), implement InitializingBean etc.

If you don't you have to do all that yourself programmatically when you initialize your scope. You would use `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanfactory()` and use the [`AutowireCapableBeanFactory`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) to wire the scope manually, using something like 
[`AutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(Object, String)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html#initializeBean%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to post-process the scope (which will also execute any registered lifecycle callbacks).